# Tensorflow-gpu not detecting GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have reinstalled tensorflow-gpu many times.Cuda and Cudnn already installed with path added but available gpu for tensorflow is always 0 for me.

Comment: For newer versions of tensorflow there is no `-gpu` version because tensorflow natively supports GPU and CPU in the same module. Your problem could be wrong version of CUDA and cuDNN.

Comment: My first install was tensorflow but its wasnt working then i did gpu.Am using tensorflow 2.3.0 with cuda 10.1 and cuDNN 7.6.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled tensorflow-gpu again but with following command.

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu=2.3 tensorflow=2.3=mkl_py38h1fcfbd6_0
```

[For more info](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/12194)