# Tensorflow 2.10.0 not detecting GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I've created a conda environment and installed tensorflow as such:

```
conda create -n foo python=3.10
conda activate foo
conda install mamba
mamba install tensorflow -c conda-forge
mamba install cudnn cudatoolkit
```

This installed TensorFlow 2.10.0. I've installed CUDA 11.2 and cuDNN 8.1, and then try to run the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(f"GPUs available: {tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')}")
```

but it just returns an empty list. I have a 3060ti that I want to use for my ML projects but TensorFlow is not detecting it. I found similar questions to mine, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65381073/tensorflow-gpu-not-using-gpu-with-cuda-cudnn), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41402409/tensorflow-doesnt-seem-to-see-my-gpu) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68117724/tensorflow-gpu-not-detecting-gpu) but they use the old version of TensorFlow, which would install `tensorflow-gpu` and is no longer supported. How can I fix this, or even attempt to troubleshoot it.

I'm using a Windows 10 machine

Output of `nvidia-smi`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 528.24       Driver Version: 528.24       CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ... WDDM  | 00000000:09:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 30%   43C    P8    16W / 200W |    809MiB /  8192MiB |      3%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      7176    C+G   ...perience\NVIDIA Share.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9240    C+G   C:\Windows\explorer.exe         N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     12936    C+G   ...cw5n1h2txyewy\LockApp.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     13652    C+G   ...e\PhoneExperienceHost.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     14020    C+G   ...2txyewy\TextInputHost.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     14888    C+G   ...ser\Application\brave.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     15112    C+G   ...5n1h2txyewy\SearchApp.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     16516    C+G   ...oft OneDrive\OneDrive.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     18296    C+G   ...aming\Spotify\Spotify.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     18624    C+G   ...in7x64\steamwebhelper.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     18672    C+G   ...\app-1.0.9010\Discord.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     18828    C+G   ...lPanel\SystemSettings.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     19284    C+G   ...Central\Razer Central.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     20020    C+G   ...arp.BrowserSubprocess.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     22912    C+G   ...8wekyb3d8bbwe\Cortana.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     24848    C+G   ...ontend\Docker Desktop.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     25804    C+G   ...y\ShellExperienceHost.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     27064    C+G   ...8bbwe\WindowsTerminal.exe    N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Output of `nvcc -V`:

```
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Feb_14_22:08:44_Pacific_Standard_Time_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.152
Build cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29618528_0
```

I ran a dummy code as such:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def make_nn():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(1,)))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd')
    return model

def dataset():
    x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
    y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y)).batch(1)



def main():
    model = make_nn()
    model.fit(dataset(), epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=9)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f"GPUs available: {tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')}")
    print(f"Built with cuda: {tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()}")

    main()
```

and it gave me the following log:

```
GPUs available: []
Built with cuda: False
2023-02-06 09:47:32.744450: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-02-06 09:47:32.779280: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:146] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
```

Looks like it's using a CPU build

Comment: At first I'd check if GPU driver is installed and up to date.

Comment: Did you create an account to NVidia then download and install cuDNN?

Comment: @Gameplay Just updated, wasn't it :(

Comment: @Corralien yes, I did

Comment: Oh @Corralien, looks like it's taking CUDA version 12 that I had installed a while back

Comment: Standard troubleshooting is to look at the tensorflow logs printed to terminal, they have all the information you need about finding GPU libraries.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy it doesn't print anything, it just starts using the CPU. I noticed it wasn't detecting it just because the training of my nn was way too slow. Is there a logfile that TensorFlow creates, or something like that that I can use to check?

Comment: There is no log file, its all printed to the terminal, so it depends on how you are running python exactly, in jupyter this is sometimes printed to the terminal running jupyter.

Comment: What does  `tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()` output?

Comment: @talonmies `tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()` returns `False`

Comment: OK, so you are using a non-GPU enabled version of Tensorflow. Probably not the one installed by conda.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy you were right, jupyter was hiding the log

Comment: Are you sure you installed TensorFlow 2.10 and not 2.11?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy well, I printed `tf.__version__` and showed 2.10, why?

Comment: Because TensorFlow 2.11 does not support GPUs in Windows anymore. Also anaconda might have tensorflow-gpu packages that you need to install.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Really? I didn't know that. If I run `mamba install tensorflow-gpu` it looks for TensorFlow 1.15

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution, but I downgraded TensorFlow back to version 2.6.0 which was previously installed and it worked, which is a bummer, I wanted to try some more recent features, but for the time being looks like this will suffice. If anyone is facing the same issues, [this is the current conda environment that I'm using](https://gist.github.com/JoaoAreias/8fba844b21f0ffe94cdeadb865ecbf59)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating another environment with python = 3.9 and tensorflow = 2.8.1.
Also, I have cuda =11.4

[image]

Comment: and thanks for dislike before 3 minute the fastest response

Comment: i add picture to believe me

Answer (score -1):

If you use conda-forge you may need to set the environment variable
CONDA_OVERRIDE_CUDA to force installing the gpu enabled version of tensorflow as explained here https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#installing-cuda-enabled-packages-like-tensorflow-and-pytorch. Under bash that would be something like

```
CONDA_OVERRIDE_CUDA="11.2" conda install "tensorflow==2.8" -c conda-forge
```