# Tensorflow doesn't detect GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

When running `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` the GPU isn't being detected. When I install `tensorflow-gpu` this error message appears (see below). How can I force TF to use my GPU (RTX 3060).

```
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Using cached tensorflow-gpu-2.12.0.tar.gz (2.6 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Requirement already satisfied: python_version>"3.7" in c:\users\noah brömme\documents\programming\04_tensorflow_face-detection_p\facedetection\facedet\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (0.0.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: tensorflow-gpu
  Building wheel for tensorflow-gpu (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for tensorflow-gpu (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for tensorflow-gpu
Failed to build tensorflow-gpu
Installing collected packages: tensorflow-gpu
  Running setup.py install for tensorflow-gpu: started
  Running setup.py install for tensorflow-gpu: finished with status 'error'
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Noah BrÃ¶mme\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xcjz7ziv\tensorflow-gpu_9acddda0038c4dff8721a51f73f1954a\setup.py", line 37, in <module>
          raise Exception(TF_REMOVAL_WARNING)
      Exception:
      
      =========================================================
      The "tensorflow-gpu" package has been removed!
      
      Please install "tensorflow" instead.
      
      Other than the name, the two packages have been identical
      since TensorFlow 2.1, or roughly since Sep 2019. For more
      information, see: pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu
      =========================================================
      
      
      [end of output]
  
...
╰─> tensorflow-gpu

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: Ignore tensorflow-gpu, look at the log produced when importing tensorflow, and look at the thousands of questions asking the same thing, for exam,ple just today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75359439/tensorflow-2-10-0-not-detecting-gpu

Comment: Ok, I downgraded to 2.10. However the GPU doesn't show up.

Comment: "look at the log produced when importing tensorflow" this is very important as it tells you which libraries are missing for GPU support.

Comment: When importing tensorflow it doesn't seem to encounter any errors

Answer (score 0):

> "TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on
> native-Windows. Starting with TensorFlow 2.11, you will need to
> install TensorFlow in WSL2, or install tensorflow-cpu and, optionally,
> try the TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin"

Please follow the step by step instructions mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) to install `TensorFlow` along with checking **Hardware and Software requirements** for the `TensorFlow` GPU support in the system.

Please make sure to [set the path](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#set_your_path) to the bin directory after downloading all the required software for the GPU setup. Let us know if the issue still perists.